# Edit: Subprocess wont open python file in new window?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.6

I have this python file in the same folder as the one being executed. And I'm trying to execute the file in a new terminal window (I'm using Linux) using subprocess. The new window opens, but its giving me the error `Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/python3 /media/root/MYDRIVE/tools/sniff/sniffer.py" (No such file or directory)`. Could anyone explain?

```
import subprocess
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-x', '/usr/bin/python3 '+ current_path+'/sniffer.py'])
```

Comment: `print(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir))`

Comment: `python3` can only be run in your local shell because it is on the `PATH`. When you start a new gnome-terminal, the binary lookup path will be different. From the terminal that works call `which python3`; use the output of this command to fully qualify the path in your script; `/path/to/pathon3` If the issue is that _snifer.py_ cannot be found, you are likely in the wrong `pwd` within your script. Again, fully qualify the path to the script. `/path/to/python3 /path/to/sniffer.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 sniffer.py\"'")
```

Comment: And `which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @Rick, can you try splitting all parts of the command now? `..., '-x', '/usr/bin/python3', '/path/to/sniffer.py']`

Comment: @MattClark Thanks, I have done that but now the new window does not open.

Comment: @Rick: Have a look at this link if you are using ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/916282/failed-to-execute-child-process-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @Vimanyu I'm using Kali Linux. Would that make a big difference? Also I installed `libSDL2-2.0` and nothing changed.

Comment: @Rick: I just updated my answer. I tested this and it is working for me on CentOS.

Comment: @Vimanyu Now I'm getting the error `Failed to execute child process "bash -c "python3 sniffer.py"" (No such file or directory`. I am using Kali Linux 2018.1

Comment: Fixed. This is what I did instead: `os.system("gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c \"/usr....""`